# Struts + Hibernate : large memory consumption arise during reading big data arrays

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2

I use hosting for my web-application(Struts + hibernate),

the hosting java memory restriction : -XX:MaxPermSize=320m.

Each user of my web application can retrieve(only reading from DB, no writing) a big array of java beans per struts actions - up to 25 MB(number_of_records_in_DB * length_of_record_in_bytes in MySQL)

Users can use my web application (retrieve data) simultaneously

**How can I optimize memory consumption?**

**Am I need to use Hibernate cashing startegy?**

```
hibernate.cfg.xml :

<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">select 1;</property>

<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</property>

<property  name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory    </property>
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

Hibernate Dao function :

public List<DataBean> listByPeriod(***) {

    **** 

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    session.beginTransaction();

    Query query = session.createQuery(hql).setDate(0, date0).setDate(1, date1);  

    List<DataBean> data = null;

    try {
          data = (List<DataBean>)query.list();

    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
    }

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();

    return data;
}

struts action + hibernate example :
String execute() {
    ***
    List<Databean> results = DataManager.listByPeriod(***); // size up to 25MB

    for (Iterator<Databean> it = results.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
       doSomething();
       ***
    }
    ***
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this data is used to display on the page consider to use pagination and read only columns which you are really need to use.

**UPDATE**
You could try to use [hibernate caching](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-cache) as you supposed

Comment: This data need to build charts, to build reports, same data uses in different actions, users can have same data

Answer (score 1):

Does Databean have the property in blob/clob type, or does it have the List, Set properties(one-to-many)? It is suggested that setting them Lazy would reduce the memory usage.

Comment: No, Databean has only Date, Integer and Double properties - no blob/clob and set/list